# @getmapping spring boot for array

Tags: java, spring-boot

I try to add a `GET` mapping to my controller, but when I test it in Postman, it shows [a Postman error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zdvxl.png), it only doesn't work for get mapping but the `POST` mapping seems okay.

Below is my controller:

```java
@RestController
public class SchoolController {
    @Autowired
    private SchoolRepository schoolRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @GetMapping("/schools/{schoolId}")
    public School getSchoolAndStudents(@PathVariable Long schoolId) {
        School school = schoolRepository.findById(schoolId).get();
        List<Student> students = studentRepository.findBySchool(school);
        school.setStudents(students);
        return school;
    }
```

Below is my model:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "school")
public class School {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "school", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Student> students;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    public void setStudents(List<Student> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "school_id")
    private School school;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public School getSchool() {
        return school;
    }

    public void setSchool(School school) {
        this.school = school;
    }
}
```

Below is my repo:

```java
@Repository
public interface SchoolRepository extends JpaRepository<School, Long> {
}

@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {
    List<Student> findBySchool(School school);
}
```

I have already tried many times, used another method to get mapping, but it is still sending the same error in my Postman like above.

Comment: You don't need to query the students, the relation is already there, probably on both sides which is the actual issue.

Comment: hi Deinum,sorry if i ask more question after this,because i'm new to learn spring,So based on you say, i should delete this line code?List<Student> students = studentRepository.findBySchool(school);

Comment: You should request `/getSchoolAndStudents/` and not `/school/` for instance.

Comment: Yes you can just return the School you found. YOu need to mark the `School` in the `Student` as `@JsonIgnore` or `@JsonBackreference`. If you don't do that you will go into a look as School has a list of students, which has a school, which has a list of students, which has a ... (Well you probably get it).

Comment: still same,i tried to test in postman after change it to schools instead,but i still having same error "Could not get response"

Comment: As stated you need to mark the field so it will beignored by jackson else you get a recursive error.

Comment: hi Deinum it works,thank you for helping me,i really appreciate your help.If you don't mind can i connect with you through your social media?

Comment: what's in the console btw ?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
@GetMapping("/schools/{schoolId}")
public School getSchoolAndStudents(@PathVariable Long id) {
    //this is finding weather the id is present in table or not
    Optional<school> finding=schoolRepository.findById(id);
    if(finding.isPresent()) {
        //if the id is present it will return the details of the school with id 
        return finding.get();
    }
    else {
        //if the id is not present it will return null
        return null;
    }
}
```